# CiviEvent in Multisite Acting Strange after Upgrade to 4.7

Tags: civievent, wordpress, multisite, 4.7

Our organizes uses Wordpress and CiviCRM, and we have multisite enabled to use one civi database across two websites (set up in WP multisite).

I upgraded to CiviCRM 4.7 this morning and it went smoothly on the main site. However, on the second site, the CiviEvent pages look strange on the website front end. It looks to me like the CSS is not loading correctly. Can anyone give me some idea as to what is happening here?

Here is an example.

Working, primary site:
http://japanphilly.org/wordpress/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/info&reset=1&id=225

Strange-looking, secondary site (same event):
http://subarucherryblossom.org/events/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/info&id=225

In addition, while logged in as an admin, the drop-down admin links which usually appear near the top of the page (Info and Settings, Location, Fees, etc.) appear not as a drop down but as a list of links... which is why I am guessing the CSS is somehow not loading right.

Comment: I've discovered that the css looks wonky because it is not loading correctly. For some reason, on my secondary site, civicrm is looking for the css at the wrong location. Instead of loading the css from the webroot (e.g. mysite.com/pathtocss) it is adding the server root to the site url (e.g. mysite.com/home/var/public_html/pathtocss). I have no clue as to why it is doing thing... It doesn't have this problem on my primary site.

Comment: Apparently something happened to the resource URLs on the secondary site... It was replacing the path I typed in with things like [civicrm.files]/ which *should* point to the right location, but doesnt seem to work. Saving the original urls in there did not work either, so I had to go into phpmyadmin and manually edit the tables to have the correct paths.

Comment: What do you have as your base URL in your civicrm.settings.php for the secondary site?

Comment: Base URL for the secondary site is set at http://subarucherryblossom.org/ which hasn't changed since before the update.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the two urls you posted you can see that one is /civicrm and the other is /events.

That suggests that when you upgraded perhaps something got messed up in the WP equivalent of settings.php.

if i change out the url and go to

http://subarucherryblossom.org/wordpress/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/info&id=225

it all looks fine to me. hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that! I don't know how things got changed, but I updated the links and it is working now.

Comment: Hm... well this worked briefly, but then it reverted to the same issue.

Look at it the source, the CiviCRM CSS is being loaded from an incorrect path for some reason. The css paths are correct on the main site but incorrect on the secondary site. I'm not sure why that would happen...